I want to know why is my mint Authority different that update Authority I am minting NFT's using metaplex libraries
I just minted NFT's and everytime I see there is an mintAuthority that not an address i know
the updateAuthority is my address connected wallet , mint address is the NFT address but when I see mintAuthority its some unknown address i'm not sure where is it coming from !
I'm not sure if I'm correct since NFT's cannot be minted again so there's some random authority that's been assigned to it so that it get the property of not minting again !


The mint authority may belong to whatever service you used to create the token. It's hard to tell without more info unfortunately!
